# How do I fix segmentation fault(core dumped) in C

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to implement the luhn's algorithm. I get the card number using get_long from the cs50 library and I put the digits in an array where I it pass to a checksum function. The program works well on my local machine but gives out a segmentation fault for some credit card numbers(not all of them) in the codespace of cs50.
I tried changing the type of the variable of the number from long to long long but the problem still persists.

Here is the source code.

```
// Implementation of the Luhn's Algorithm

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int checksum(int digits[], size_t n);

int main()
{
    // Prompt user for credit card number
    long long number = get_long("Number: ");

    // Calculate length of number
    int n;
    long long tmp = number;
    for (n = 0; tmp != 0; n++)
    {
        tmp = tmp / 10;
    }

    // Put the digits in an array and pass it to the checksum function
    tmp = number;
    int digits[n];
    for (int i = 0; tmp != 0; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            tmp = number;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp = tmp / 10;
        }
        digits[i] = tmp % 10;
    }
    bool a = checksum(digits, n);

    int first_digit = digits[n - 1];
    int sec_digit = digits[n - 2];

    // Check if number satisfies checksum and corresponding pattern
    // for valid card numbers and prints out the corresponding matching
    // card pattern brand
    if (a && (n == 15 && first_digit == 3) && (sec_digit == 4 || sec_digit == 7))
    {
        printf("AMEX\n");
    }
    else if (a && (n == 13 || n == 16) && (first_digit == 4))
    {
        printf("VISA\n");
    }
    else if (a && (n == 16 && first_digit == 5) && (sec_digit == 1 || sec_digit == 2 || sec_digit == 3 || sec_digit == 4
             || sec_digit == 5))
    {
        printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
        return 0;
    }


}

// Checksum implementation
int checksum(int numbers[], size_t n)
{
    // Variable to store result
    int result = 0;

    // Store the numbers array in a duplicate variable
    int duplicate[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        duplicate[i] = 0;
        duplicate[i] = numbers[i];
    }

    // Loop to add the product's digits'
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i += 2)
    {
        // Multiply the digits by 2 starting from the second to last digit and their digits' together
        duplicate[i] *= 2;

        // Check if the result is not a single number
        if (duplicate[i] / 10 != 0)
        {
            int tmp = duplicate[i];
            tmp = (tmp / 10) + (tmp % 10);
            result += tmp;
        }
        else
        {
            result += duplicate[i];
        }
    }

    // Add the result to the digits of the numbers we didn't multiply by 2
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2)
    {
        result += duplicate[i];
    }

    // Return 0 or 1 based on results
    if (result % 10 == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I tried changing the type of the variable for storing the card number from long to long long and I also tried testing it on different credit card numbers and some of them yield segmentation faults and others don't. This credit card number in particular 4003600000000014 results in a segmentation fault which is supposed to print out "VISA\n" but on my local machine works perfectly fine.

Comment: Card nbers, phone numbers etc. are not really numbers. They are strings of digits and should be represented and processed as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Allan Wind found the problem. Here's another way to do it.

```
int digits[n];
tmp = number;
for( int i = 0; tmp; i++ )
{
    digits[i] = tmp % 10; // right most digit value
    tmp /= 10; // shift right (base 10)
}
```

It's possible to reduce the lines of code if one allows a generous buffer of integers (only using as many as needed.)

```
int digits[64], len = 0;
tmp = number;
for( int i = 0; tmp; i++ )
{
    digits[i] = tmp % 10; // right most digit value
    tmp /= 10; // shift right (base 10)
    len++;
}
```

Now, one loop both separates the values and determines the length of the card number.

In fact, the code could go even further...

```
int digits[64], len = 0;
int prfx0 = 0, prfx1 = 0; // two "prefix" values
tmp = number;
for( int i = 0; tmp; i++ )
{
    prfx1 = prfx0; // eventually 10 <= x <= 99
    prfx0 = tmp; // eventually 1 <= x <= 9 
    digits[i] = tmp % 10; // right most digit value
    tmp /= 10; // shift right (base 10)
    len++; // counting the length
}
// prfx0 now contains the leftmost digit's value
// prfx1 now contains the 2 digit value of the 2 leftmost digits.

/* checksum validation code goes here */

if( a && len == 15 && 51 <= prfx1 && prfx1 <= 55 )
    printf( "Mastercard" );
```

Finally, let's go all the way with this single loop:

```
int prfxTmp = 0, prfxTwo = 0; // two "prefix" values
int len = 0, chkSum = 0;
for( tmp = number; tmp; tmp /= 10 )
{
    len++; // counting the length

    prfxTwo = prfxTmp; // eventually 10 <= x <= 99
    prfxTmp = tmp; // eventually 1 <= x <= 9 

    int digit = tmp % 10; // right most digit value

    if( len & 1 ) // works if chksum digit involved
        chkSum += digit;
    else
        chkSum += (2 * digit) / 10 + (2 * digit) % 10;
}

if( len == 15 && 51 <= prfxTwo && prfxTwo <= 55 && chkSum % 10 == 0 )
    printf( "Mastercard" );
/* and more possibilities */
```

Comment: @AllanWind thanks very much for your help. I appreciate it. The program works fine now

Answer (score 1):

You iterate over `digits` but don't limit `i` to less than `n`.  Optionally, you can simplify the check `tmp != 0` to just `tmp` and the `tmp` assignment:

```
    int digits[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n && tmp; i++)
    {
        tmp = i ? tmp / 10 : number;
        digits[i] = tmp % 10;
    }
```